# Java SSH client with GUI, Mindterm alternative

Tags: java, ssh

In our project (CMS) we are currently using Mindterm for launching SSH terminal to Network Elements and different Virtual Machines. Client download .jnlp file that launch Swing based GUI with ssh terminal to configured address.

Since mindterm is getting out of support at the end of this year (2021), we are looking for replacement, my question is can anyone recommend something providing similar functionality, we don't want into writing this by our own.

Thanks

P.S. I know that e.g. Putty, mRemoteNG exist but customer want to have ability start preconfigured with IP address terminal from CMS application.

Comment: You can start putty with command line parameters that say it where it should connect to: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.75/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline